# TypeError: 'ResultSet' object is not callable - python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

i searched other people who got the same error, but i don't think i has the same problem.  i want to get the name for each item on the website i think is `<h2 class = "heading">`. but i have no idea why i get this error and i don't know what to do. This is the website's URL in my code https://www.jetsetter.com/magazine/cool-tech-gadgets-on-amazon/,

code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

res_item = requests.get('https://www.jetsetter.com/magazine/cool-tech-gadgets-on-amazon/')
bs_item = BeautifulSoup(res_item.text,'html.parser')
list_item = bs_item.find_all('h2',class_ ="heading")

for item_print in list_item():
    print(item_print)
```

and i get the error:
`line 8, in <module> for item_print in list_item(): TypeError: 'ResultSet' object is not callable`

also when i print list_item out it will also show some part of the HTML code like

```
</h2>, <h2 class="heading">
                    Tile Mate with Replaceable Battery
                </h2>
```

but i only want it to show the string on the second line.

Comment: why do you have parenthesis for ```list_item``` remove ```()```

Comment: You are trying to call `list_item` by adding `()`, however it's not callable. so remove the `()`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in your code here `item_print in list_item()` use `item_print in list_item:` instead

Try this

```
import requests
from bs4 import  BeautifulSoup

res_item = requests.get('https://www.jetsetter.com/magazine/cool-tech-gadgets-on-amazon/')
bs_item = BeautifulSoup(res_item.text,'html.parser')
list_item = bs_item.find_all('h2',class_ ="heading")

for item_print in list_item:
    print(item_print.get_text(strip=True))
```